# How can I create dictionary specifying keys names as a input variable

Tags: python, variables, dictionary

I'm using a dictionary to create a list of variables:

```
def split_list(list_,size,name):
    fragment_number = len(list_)/size + 1 
    d={}
    for x in range(1,fragment_number+1):
            d["north_carolina_cities{0}".format(x)]=list_[(x-1)*size:x*size]
    return d
```

This function takes a list as input and split it in several items of a dict, but I'm not able to use the variable 'name' to regerate the keys of a dictionary  so I have to change the name manually each time: "north_carolina_cities{0}"

How can I integrate this process into the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
def split_list(list_, size, name):
    d = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(list_):
        d[name + str(i+1)] = x
    return d
```

This is a simplified version of what you have because I'm not sure why you are obtaining fragment_number by dividing the list length, and then multiplying by list length to get your index.

Comment: Where can I find the documentation of the for loop as you are using it? with to variables: in, c?
I'm doing that because I'm spliting the list in chuncks of the same size, so I'm calculating the number of segments by  len(list_)/size + 1